# Linear Circuit Analysis: Source Transformation of DC Network

Tags: circuit-analysis, analysis, network, delta

[image]

[image]

The 1st (upper) picture is the given problem. The 2nd (lower) picture is my attemps to the solution. 
I neglected the middle resistor in bridge circuit, resistor in parallel with voltage source, and resistor in series with current source. But now I'm stuck, any hint?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just noticed this. I'll just do some broad hand-sweeps quickly through the schematic you provided. Hopefully, I won't make any gross mistakes in the process. And hopefully, it may help a little.

1. Mentally, I'm treating your node A as ground. So I'm calling that
   \$0V\$, arbitrarily.
2. This makes the resistor bridge in the lower left corner completely
   irrelevant, so you can just ignore it entirely. You have a current
   source driving current into it and that will set up a voltage across the bridge. But it is completely irrelevant
   because your current source has infinite impedance and it completely
   isolates the bridge circuit from the rest of the circuit. So I'm
   mentally eliminating \$R_2\$, \$R_3\$, \$R_4\$, \$R_5\$, and
   \$R_{20}\$ and just hooking the current source directly to node A
   (ground.) That sweeps away a lot of unnecessary work. (Another way
   of looking at this case is to realize that it doesn't matter at all
   what the current source is sourcing into. It will source into it,
   period. So if you just hooked that end of the current source to
   ground, you'd still have the same situation for the rest of the
   circuit. Same deal, any way you look at it. It's just a pointless
   distraction.)
3. Of course, I'm mentally combining \$R_{19}\$ and \$R_{21}\$ into a
   single resistor (\$R_a = 2R\$), \$R_{17}\$ and \$R_{18}\$ into another
   resistor (\$R_b = 2R\$), and also notice that \$R_{15}\$ and \$R_{16}\$
   are also wired in parallel, so I mentally also combine them into yet
   another single resistor, which I'll call \$R_x = \frac{2}{3}R\$.
4. This last resistor, \$R_x\$, is interesting because it is in series
   from node B back to the node that \$U_1\$ and \$I_1\$ also share. So
   I'm going to think of this shared node as node C, for now.
5. Now that I've got this new node C, I can see that \$R_{10}\$,
   \$R_b\$, \$R_6\$, \$R_{12}\$, and \$R_a\$ all form a nice bridge,
   again, from node C to ground (node A.) The resistance of this bridge
   can be lumped as \$\frac{4}{3} R\$.
6. Hmm. That just leaves that rats nest involving a couple of voltage
   sources. There is no way any of the current needed by the current
   source, \$I_1\$, can be coming by way of \$R_1\$ or \$R_7\$, because
   their voltages are fixed firmly (or, in effect, bridged over by the
   \$0\Omega\$ characteristics of \$U_1\$ and \$U_2\$.) The same is
   true for \$R_{13}\$, \$R_{14}\$, and \$R_9\$. So all that can be
   ignored. The voltage sources in effect bypass all those resistors.
   So all of the current being driven by \$I_1\$ must be coming
   entirely through either \$R_8\$ or else through the equivalent
   resistance of the bridge already mentioned in (5) above.

The equivalent is now looking like this:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f6Vnj6.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Convert the voltage source (\$U_1 + U_2\$) and series resistor into a Norton equivalent, sum the currents, convert back to the Thevenin voltage equivalent if you want, and get something like this:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fJauoD.png)</sup>

I'll let you mess around with the algebra on the voltage source.

EDIT: Well, after an hour waiting for you... Here it is: \$V_s = \frac{U_1+U_2}{2} -\frac{2}{3}I_1 R\$

NOTE @hello: Just look and see that the two voltage sources are effectively zero impedance. Shorts, so to speak, with a voltage characteristic that is more than \$0V\$. They completely bypass the resistors I mentioned in point #6. That's one way. Or, take the perspective of the of the current source. Where can it *pull* its current from? It can't pull anything extra through \$R_1\$ or \$R_7\$, because if it did, the voltage drop across those two would have to increase. But it can't increase. There are voltage sources across them. That makes pulling any of the current source current through them impossible. If you think about it closely, the nodes relating to \$R_{13}\$, \$R_{14}\$, and \$R_9\$ are also completely *determined* by those voltage sources (the shared node is determined by the other nodes and the other nodes are determined by the voltage sources, so once again the current source can't pull extra through there, either.) That does NOT mean that the current source can't be pulling through the two voltage sources, though. It can do that. So that just leaves that little \$R_8\$ (plus, of course, that other bridge equivalent I mentioned.)

Comment: Thank you so much for your detail explanation. After I follow your way, I've found the same results. Ignoring different value resistor in the middle of bridge circuit, that's my fault. Also, I didn't realize that \$R_{16}\$ and \$R_{15}\$ are in parallel. But after reading your point number 6 about that rats nets, I still don't get it, why we just left with the voltage sources and \$R_8\$? Can you give more explanation or any example?

Comment: See added NOTE to you.

Comment: Okay, thank you very much for your input, I didn't know about this before. Once again, thanks a lot for sharing.

Comment: @hello: No problem. Electronics is very much also about acquiring _simplifying perspectives_ about things and applying them in a rigorous fashion. It's like acquiring tools. At first you are using a handsaw to cut everything and spending lots of time adjusting things to fit each other. Later, you get a table saw and specialized tools and some of the work goes so much faster. Treat your brain like that. Add tools, use them, keep them sharp, and be ready to have someone else come around and teach you where you are still making mistakes, too! You will never know enough to not make more mistakes.

Answer (score 0):

> I neglected the middle resistor in bridge circuit,

um, you can't do that! it's plain wrong. I don't know how you came to the conclusion you could do that.

In fact, this is like the last transform I'd do. Start with resistors that are directly without doubt and branches serial, or parallel.

> resistor in parallel with voltage source

there's more than that single transistor!

Comment: okay, now I transform the bridge circuit with wyw-to-delta transformation and get the value. Thanks for your reminder. But since it's in series with current source, I can neglect it, right? Also, Is my wye-to-delta transformation (in the picture) is already right? I just realized that 5R in the middle of delta transormation is also parallel to the voltage source, but what I have to do with this then?

Comment: I just remember that I cannot neglect the middle resistor in the bridge circuit, except all the resistor values are the same.

Comment: "it's plain wrong". Why? The two dividers (R-R and 2R-2R) will both split the ddp exactly in two and the middle resistor will see the same potential on both its terminals. That means no current will flow. Where's the difference wrt an open circuit?  (BTW, I did a delta-wye transformation of the 2R-4R bridge and it came out a value indipendent of the 'bridging' R).

Comment: Oh, I see now, there are two such bridges. The horizontal one (3R-6R, 1R-4R) does not lend itself to this sort of trick.

Comment: you still haven't found the other resistor in parallel to  a voltage source!

Comment: **It still seems you're basing your simplification purely on a set of rules that you've learned by heart, not on a understanding what happens below. That's not a good thing!**